# Does the metaphor of righteous men as Jerusalem's walls appear anywhere in the Torah?

Tags: yerushalayim-jerusalem, dream, allegory-mashal

I had a dream in which God spoke to me. He told me: "See these ruins of the wall (in Jerusalem)? These ruins are not ruins, these are the righteous men of Israel." -i.e. righteous men of Israel are like a wall which protects Jerusalem. Questions:

1. Is there a metaphor of righteous men as Jerusalem's walls anywhere in the Torah?
2. Is there a metaphor of men and ruins in the Torah?
3. What are some possible interpetations of the dream based on your knowledge of the Torah?

Comment: If you’re trying to interpret dreams, I suggest performing Hatavas Chalom (traditionally done the day immediately following the dream), or at a minimum talking with your Rabbi.

Comment: 1 & 2: See Midrash Eichah Rabba ([petichta n.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=8NgtAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA82&ots=UyFv0uQMta&dq=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%AA%D7%90&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false); or [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/eyha/0-2.htm#2)) where the epithet for these said protectors is “נטורי קרתא”. See also Bavli ([BB 7b-8a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.7b.14?with=all&lang=bi)) where they’re considered ‘Guardians (walls) of the city’.

Comment: @Oliver Answer?

Comment: @DonielF partial, I guess. Have had it, if you will.

Comment: @Oliver you have answered my question I guess

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you were listening to the song "**Shomrei hafkid l'ircha kol hayom v'kol halaila*" which in turn is inspired by the verse in Isaiah 62:6-7 "Upon your walls, O Jerusalem, I have set watchmen, Who shall never be silent By day or by night. O you, the LORD’s remembrancers (sic), Take no rest - And give no rest to Him, Until He establish Jerusalem And make her renowned on earth." *Targum Yonasan*  [identifies these "watchmen"](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.62.6?lang=bi&p2=Targum_Jonathan_on_Isaiah.62.6&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) as the *tzaddikim* who constantly mourn the destruction of Jerusalem and the *Beis HaMikdash*.

Comment: See here for a discussion of the pasuk in hebrew: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%A1%D7%91_%D7%95

Comment: Well, Rashi identifies them as angels while Yonatan identifies the walls as the forefathers. See https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Isaiah.62.6?lang=bi

Comment: Also, the watchmen on the walls are not exactly the metaphor we're discussing as we are talking about the walls themselves. Nevertheless, your answer is helpful

Comment: @DanWeisberg as does the gemara in Menachos.

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud Megilah 3b towards the bottom discusses the law a walled city from the time of Joshua ben Nun (today only Jerusalem) that is destroyed. (This was very relevant from 1948-67). The Talmud first proposes that this means the wall was destroyed. This is rejected in favor of interpreting this as "a city that is destroyed from its Ten Idle Scholars in the Synagogue." Based on the principal that even a *hava ameina* (proposal that is not ultimately accepted) in the Talmud has significance, this might be taken as a hint that there is a connection between Walls (and their destruction) and Torah Scholars or Righteous Men.

---

Also consider "The death of the righteous is difficult like the destruction of the Holy Temple." (Rosh Hashana 18b)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the sources)